# What are vault tickets in DCUO used for?

Tags: dc-universe-online

I just started playing DC Universe online and I have a vault ticket, it says use it to teleport to the vault and have free inventory space. Is there stuff there that I can just grab for free or something? I don't want to use it til I find out whether I should save it for right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vault is a special minigame which contains lots of presents falling from the sky that you must break open. They can contain currency, styles, and marks.  More rare are trinkets, and gear.  Some gear can even be account-bound instead of character-bound.

The vault can be queued from the On Duty menu.  It is locked based on your subscription level: Once a day Legendary, Once every 3 days Premium, Once every five days, Free.

You are given a vault ticket while levelling to introduce you to the Vault.  This is in addition to your queued instance, and does not affect the lockout.  Vault tickets are also available via the Marketplace, and might be included in specific bundle crates.  They do not expire; if you queue the Vault while levelling, you can save the ticket for later, and still complete the mission.

Comment: Cool thanks for that ... you know it is Free to Play now?

Comment: @JustinCoolestnerdRobinson Yeah I know it's free to play now, just occupied with other games at the moment. Will probably give it another go later on.